# Google search console tool, changing the language of the admin panel

Tags: google-search-console

I have a problem recently my client have added my account to look after a website bugs and corrections on google search console, my account language by default is english, but on the search console is German language, how can i set it back to english ?
Browser language i check it is EN
My main google account lang is EN
but on google search console it is DE, how i can set it to EN ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Hey Mohamed, I'm looking for the same thing, did you find the option anywhere?

Comment: Hey Mauriblint, I don't exactly remember what i have done to fix it, i remember i go to google account and changed the lang over and over, and also in the chrome browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on **Settings** Icon

[image]

Click on **Languages**

[image]

Choose your preferred **Language** and **Save**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the preferred language in [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/language).